# Using a LED as a debug serial port

Tags: serial, debugging, optoelectronics

I want to add a debug serial output port to a device that's sealed in epoxy. I plan to use one of three existing 3mm [LEDs](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/VISH_S_A0009634321_1-2570662.pdf) (red 617nm, green 568nm, or yellow 588nm), ±30° angle, that emerge from the surface of the device:
[image: closeup of leds]

These LEDs are internally connected to (PIC18F252) CPU output pins thru 330Ω pull-ups to +5V.
[image: schematic]

I plan to do serial big-banging to a UART-to-USB (FTDI FT232RL). I've done that in the past @1Mbit/s with a physical connection, it was very convenient.

My problem is turning the light out from one of these leds into a CMOS signal.

Any device/schematic to suggest? What kind of rise and fall time/delay would I get, which would limit bit rate? How much do I need to insulate the receiving device from ambient light?

Note: I want to be "as fast as possible", like at least 50 kbit/s, to 850kbit/s ideally (the maximum I can easily reach in software). I can't change the LEDs to infrared as in IrDA, but I can use any modulation doable in software bit-banging, e.g. 300ns pulses.

Since the LED ports are push-pull in 5V CMOS, I'd expect <20ns rise and fall time at that point, but I guess that's considerably increased across the LED.

Comment: Have you considered IRDA?

Comment: Start by measuring the rise/fall times of your LEDs since that will set your maximum symbol rate. Depending on your circuit they may switch a lot slower than you expect (and almost certainly much slower than 100ns of your CPU clock).

Comment: You'll be limited by the receiver. 4800 or 9600 baud would be pretty easy, 1M baud not so easy. Look up design of photodiode front ends (also filtering the light and keeping ambient light away). If you just need one for your test equipment so cost ($$$) is not too important, I think Highland Technology in SF makes a box that was designed with Phil Hobbs.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have some specific speed you wish to achieve. Or is this just "as fast as possible" (within reasonable costs/efforts)?

I see several types of devices you might use :

- photo-diodes
- photo-transistors
- photo-resistors
- high speed cameras (I wouldn't recommend those, excepted if you which to work on many different types of devices using the same hardware).

Then, in order to choose the right solution, I would go for the following order :

1. get (or approximate) the wavelength of your LEDs (if given by data-sheet, then it's perfect, if not, if you have the needed equipment, measure it, and if not, try comparing to known colors). So you should get 3 approximations of wavelengths (one per LED)
2. try to get an idea of the amount of light emitted by the LEDs (at least an order of magnitude).
3. look for receptors at the wavelengths with low enough rise times, and working with the amount of light you get
4. work out the rest of the circuit.

The schematics will depend on the choice of device. With photo-diode or photo-resistor, you will need some analog circuitry, but you can tune the sensitivity. With a photo-transistor, it's probably easier to go "digital", but probably harder to tune the threshold.

For the rise/fall times, [this photo-diode](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Rohm%20PDFs/RPM-075PT.pdf) gives 10µs and [this photo-transistor](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Everlight%20PDFs/ALS-PT17-51C,L177,TR8.pdf) gives 0.11/0.22ms .NB : I took the values for the first component I found working with red and providing rise/fall times : I'm not saying that a photo diode is faster than a photo-transistor : those values is just to say what can be achieved, and probably more can be achieved if you spend time looking for the fastest devices.

NB : the LEDs on the board might also be the limiting element, but I would guess not.

For the insulation from ambient light :

- with photo-transistors, it would be good to have a huge difference between ambient light and LED (so rather good covering will be useful : putting a cardboard box over your circuit should be enough)
- for photo-diodes and photo-resistors : as long as there is a perceptible change in light, it should be possible to extract the information. But the bigger the difference between on and off, the easier the processing. (you can transfer some information even in very noisy environment, but it is difficult, and you might end up needing signal-correction bits)

Comment: Both sensors you link to are phototransistors, and the first has a best-case response time of 200 usec with a 1k load.

Answer (score 3):

Rise time is greatest when you have series R and current shunt C that results in the classic 1st order LPF with asymptotic T(63%)= RC.  Also all semi's have capacitance that varies with size, ESR resistance and bias.  {e.g. Diodes, LED's, Photo Diodes and CMOS FETs}.

Having designed a LED luminosity tester, I chose the detector to be recessed in a low reflective black aperture to  block all stray light.   This worked well at a distance of 1 m but  then these were > 16,000 mcd, 5 mm, 30 deg LEDs.

This method is basically the same as used by [IRDA IC's](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/dc112a.pdf) which is your best bet . The demo board will save you time and money.

[image]

I suggest a 5mm Photo diode (PD) or Phototransistor (PT) with black heat shrink as LED and Fluorescent ceiling light flicker might cause noise.

A comparator will offer the best switching speed but choosing the threshold may shift the rise vs fall time.  The load capacitance and low output current suggests the rise time may be worse than the drive LED which could be << 10 us. This RC=T must be designed to be less than your desired delay for your bit-bang.  Use a self-clocking continuous code like bi-phase with a simple decoder or a UART to receive data.  Red may be the best for PD spectral sensitivity.

For a discrete design, I would choose a PD over a PT as the gain in 0.4 uA/mW of light conversion is very accurate compared  to the wide variation of hFE in a transistor especially for low Vce < 0.7V.

Then output directly into the IRDA chip or a discrete design as follows;

- a TIA (Op Amp) with high GBW (>> 10MHz) near the PT for precise gain with high BW and de-noise with a supply cap next to IC. Then output to a CMOS LOGIC IC.

This is a common design for high SNR data transfer , error-free, if >> 20 dB SNR and accurate slicer threshold  for symmetrical slew rate and SNR in each logic state.  Transition dependant detection may offer better SNR for clock and data recovery if you are detecting a weak signal but integrate and dump detection offers the best SNR.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into  [SFH3710](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/43564.pdf) + [LT1328](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1328.html) or similar, and black tape over the red diode+sensor.

Comment: black heatshrink tubing is  better if you can get it and not shiny tape. Allow 2:1 shrinkage

Comment: Tubing won't stick, I'm afraid; see the picture I added.

Comment: OK I'm sure you can use you imagination to capture the light with high SNR and block the ambient light.but still make it visible. such as a reflector for 90 deg detector. or something

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the LT1328, or a similar IRDA receiver - although designed for infra-red, it should work with a visible light photodiode, and you don't have to use IRDA encoding.

It will accept modulated or unmodulated light signals; the benefit of the former is that you get better rejection of ambient light - the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1328f.pdf) explains this in detail.